# Error NumberFormatException on Java

Tags: java, android

I have the following exception trying to manipulate a value to be added;
thank you very much for your help

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "20,000"
java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
```

Comment: Is the comma in `"20,000"` supposed to be a decimal separator (and the value is twenty) or is it a group separator (and the value is twenty thousand)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to parse your `String`<sup>**1**</sup>. Something like,

```
String str = "20,000";
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en_US"));
NumberFormat nfIT = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALIAN); 
try {
    System.out.println(nf.parse(str)); // <-- 20000
    System.out.println(nfIT.parse(str)); // <-- 20
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For more options see [Customizing Formats (The Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

<sup>**1**<sub>Being sure to pass the appropriate `Locale` to match your expected output.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is the right approach, but note that the locale is quite possible one where the comma is the decimal separator, not a group separator.

Comment: @TedHopp That's why I gave an example specifying a `Locale` (it's unclear from the question what OP expects).

Comment: Right. I just think the answer would be nicer if you picked a locale (like, e.g., `Locale.FRANCE`) for which `"20,000"` would parse successfully.

Comment: @TedHopp Done. [Decimal Mark: Examples of Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use) contains a table of similar locales.

Answer (score -1):

You don't use comma as a separator in numbers.

You have to use `20000` instead of `20,000`.

EDIT:

as @MitchWeaver mentioned, you can also substitute comma to underescore, making it `20_000`

Comment: you can use underscores, for example 20_000 is acceptable.

Comment: @MitchWeaver oh yeah, you're right. Will add that in. Thanks!

Comment: The comma here is quite possibly a decimal separator (for a non-US locale).